# cs50 pset6 error in load or index function

Tags: c, indexing, load, cs50

I finished implementing all the functions, but my code fails the second check. I am not sure exactly where the problem lies, but it is probably either in my load or index function, since my code successfully went through the first check. Could someone help me figure it out? Oh, and for some reason, my GDB is not working. Thanks in advance!

Here is my code:

```
char *indexes(const char *path) {
    char *copy = malloc(strlen(path)); 
    strcpy(copy, path); 

    char *php = "/index.php\0";
    char *html = "/index.html\0"; 

    char *check_php = malloc(strlen(copy) + strlen(php));
    char *check_html = malloc(strlen(copy) + strlen(html)); 

    check_php = strcat(copy, php); 
    check_html = strcat(copy, html); 

    if (access(check_php, F_OK) == 0)
        return check_php;
    else
    if (access(check_html, F_OK) == 0)
        return check_html; 

    return NULL;
}

bool load(FILE *file, BYTE **content, size_t *length) {
    char *store = malloc(5000); 
    int count = 0; 
    char c; 

    do {
        c = fgetc(file);

        if (feof(file))
            break; 
        else
        if (count % 5000 == 0)
            store = realloc(store, count + 5000);

        store[count] = c;
        count++; 
    } while (true); 

    *content = &store[0]; 
    *length = count;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

There are many problems in your code:

- There is a classic bug in function `indexes()`:

  ```
  char *copy = malloc(strlen(path)); 
  strcpy(copy, path);
  ```

  You must allocate one more byte for the null terminator:

  ```
  char *copy = malloc(strlen(path) + 1);
  strcpy(copy, path);
  ```

  Or you can use Posix function `strdup()` if available on your system:

  ```
  char *copy = strdup(path);
  ```
- A similar problem for your concatenation attempt:

  ```
  char *check_php = malloc(strlen(copy) + strlen(php));
  char *check_html = malloc(strlen(copy) + strlen(html)); 

  check_php = strcat(copy, php); 
  check_html = strcat(copy, html);
  ```

  You do not allocate enough memory, **plus** you do not copy the strings into the allocated memory, instead you concatenate to the end of `copy` which is already full. You should instead write:

  ```
  char *check_php = malloc(strlen(copy) + strlen(php) + 1);
  char *check_html = malloc(strlen(copy) + strlen(html) + 1); 

  strcpy(check_php, copy);
  strcpy(check_php, php);

  strcpy(check_html, copy);
  strcpy(check_html, html);
  ```
- You do not `free` the strings you no longer use before leaving this function.  This is sloppy and results in a memory leak.

There are more issues in function `load()`, that are less urgent:

- The return value from `fgetc()` should be stored into an `int`.  The way you check for end of file, while not technically wrong, is error prone and not recommended, you should instead write this:

  ```
  int c = fgetc(fp);
  if (c == EOF)
      break;
  ```
- The reallocation scheme is redundant: if `count == 0` you invoke `realloc()` with the same size as your initial `malloc()` call.  You could just initialize `store` to `NULL` and only rely on `realloc` for allocation.  If the file is empty, `*length` would be set to `0` and `*bytes` to `NULL`, which should be OK.

  An alternative if to reallocate the `store` to the actual size read before storing the pointer to `*bytes`.
- `do { ... } while (true);` is not reader friendly: it would be much better to use `for (;;) { ... }` to tell the reader immediately about the nature of this infinite loop.

Answer (score 2):

There are many bugs in the code. I've created two versions. One with the bugs annotated and corrected. The other cleaned up and simplified.

Here is the annotated version with `#if 0 /*original code*/ #else /*fixed code*/ #endif`:

```
char *
indexes(const char *path)
{
    // NOTE/BUG: malloc for string must allow for EOS char
#if 0
    char *copy = malloc(strlen(path));
#else
    char *copy = malloc(strlen(path) + 1);
#endif

    // NOTE/BUG: no need to duplicate path -- it can be used directly
    strcpy(copy, path);

    // NOTE/BUG: the \0 is redundant
#if 0
    char *php = "/index.php\0";
    char *html = "/index.html\0";
#else
    char *php = "/index.php";
    char *html = "/index.html";
#endif

    // NOTE/BUG: malloc for string must allow for EOS char
#if 0
    char *check_php = malloc(strlen(copy) + strlen(php));
    char *check_html = malloc(strlen(copy) + strlen(html));
#else
    char *check_php = malloc(strlen(copy) + strlen(php) + 1);
    char *check_html = malloc(strlen(copy) + strlen(html) + 1);
#endif

    // NOTE/BUG: copy doesn't have enough space to hold the concat and is wrong
    // NOTE/BUG: this is trashing the above values and, thus, leaking memory
#if 0
    check_php = strcat(copy, php);
    check_html = strcat(copy, html);
#else
    strcpy(check_php,copy);
    strcat(check_php,php);
    strcpy(check_html,copy);
    strcat(check_html,html);
#endif

    // NOTE/BUG: this is leaking memory of the unused check_html
#if 0
    if (access(check_php, F_OK) == 0)
        return check_php;
#else
    if (access(check_php, F_OK) == 0) {
        free(check_html);
        return check_php;
    }
#endif

    // NOTE/BUG: this is leaking memory of the unused check_php
#if 0
    if (access(check_html, F_OK) == 0)
        return check_html;
#else
    if (access(check_html, F_OK) == 0) {
        free(check_php);
        return check_html;
    }
#endif

    // NOTE/BUG: this is leaking memory of the unused check_php and check_html
#if 1
    free(check_html);
    free(check_php);
#endif
    return NULL;
}
```

Here is the cleaned up version:

```
char *
indexes(const char *path)
{
    char *php = "/index.php";
    char *html = "/index.html";
    size_t plen = strlen(path);
    char *file;

    file = malloc(plen + strlen(php) + 1);
    strcpy(file,path);
    strcat(file,php);
    if (access(file, F_OK) == 0)
        return file;
    free(file);

    file = malloc(plen + strlen(html) + 1);
    strcpy(file,path);
    strcat(file,html);
    if (access(file, F_OK) == 0)
        return file;
    free(file);

    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm apologize if this is not the case, but shouldn't you allocate more memory for copy? By definition of strcat (char *strcat(char *dest, const char *src))
Parameters
dest -- This is pointer to the destination array, which should contain a C string, and **should be large enough to contain the concatenated resulting string.**  But you allocate for copy only strlen of path.